# NestJS: How to transform an array in a @Query object

Tags: nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I'm new to NestJS and I am trying to fill a filter DTO from query Parameters.

Here is what I have:

Query:

localhost:3000/api/checklists?stations=114630,114666,114667,114668

Controller

```
@Get()
public async getChecklists(@Query(ValidationPipe) filter: ChecklistFilter): Promise<ChecklistDto[]> {
    // ...
}
```

DTO

```
export class ChecklistFilter {

    @IsOptional()
    @IsArray()
    @IsString({ each: true })
    @Type(() => String)
    @Transform((value: string) => value.split(','))
    stations?: string[];

    // ...
}
```

With this, the class validator does not complain, however, in the filter object stations is not actually an array but still a single string.

I want to transform it into an array within the validation pipe. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Btw. it should be:
@Transform(({value}) => value.split(','))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass an instance of the `ValidationPipe` instead of the class, and in doing so you can pass in options such as `transform: true` which will make `class-validator`**and** `class-transformer` run, which should pass back the transformed value.

```js
@Get()
public async getChecklists(@Query(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true })) filter: ChecklistFilter): Promise<ChecklistDto[]> {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 14):

This can be handled without a separate DTO class using the `ParseArrayPipe`:

```
@Get()
findByIds(
  @Query('ids', new ParseArrayPipe({ items: Number, separator: ',' }))
  ids: number[],
) {
  console.log(ids);
  console.log(Array.isArray(ids)); //returns true
  return 'This action returns users by ids';
}
```

ref: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#parsing-and-validating-arrays

Comment: this was almost exactly what i needed, thank you! only exception is i needed array of strings instead of numbers but that was easy enough to figure out :)

Comment: But this doesn't validate the query parameters

Comment: I believe it's supposed to at least - https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5467

Answer (score 12):

```
export class ChecklistFilter {
    
            @IsOptional()
            @IsArray()
            @IsString({ each: true })
            @Type(() => String)
            @Transform(({ value }) => value.split(','))
            stations?: string[];
        
            // ...
        }
```

--

```
     @Get()
     public async getChecklists(@Query() filter: ChecklistFilter): Promise<ChecklistDto[]> {
                // ...
            }
```

- "class-transformer": "^0.4.0"
- "class-validator": "^0.13.1"

Comment: Hi, any idea on how to achieve this for an array of numbers in a query param? imagine im trying to validate [www.url.com/path?ids=1,2,3] , where [ids] should be an array of numbers, and nothing else. tried converting your answer, but with no success so far.

Comment: `@IsArray()
@IsInt({ each: true })
@Transform(({ value }) => value.trim().split(',').map(id=>Number(id)))
@ApiProperty({
 type: [Number],
 format: 'form'
})
ids?: number[];`

**/path?ids=1,2,3,4**

Answer (score 5):

You can change your initial query a bit:

```
localhost:3000/api/checklists?stations[]=114630&stations[]=114666&stations[]=114667&stations[]=114668
```

And your controller:

```
@Get()
public async getChecklists(@Query('stations') filter: string[]): Promise<ChecklistDto[]> {
    // ...
}
```

This way the default mechanism will work fine and will convert query params into string array and no any additional dependencies or handling required.

You also can wrap it with your DTO if needed, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

the only problem you had there is in the order of validations. You can do it like this:

```
export class ChecklistFilter {

        @IsOptional()
        @Transform((params) => params.value.split(',').map(Number))
        @IsInt({ each: true })
        stations?: number[]
    
        // ...
    }
```

If you want numbers instead of ints: @IsNumber({}, { each: true })

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, what works for me is apply a custom transform:

```js
export class ChecklistFilter {
  @ApiProperty({ type: [Number] })
  @IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  @Transform((item) => item.value.map((v) => parseInt(v, 10)))
  stations?: number[];
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Todays, with the version of class transformer

```
"class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
"class-validator": "^0.14.1",
```

I did it like this, for check UUIDSv4 like this: ***ade3f65f-ee35-4224-ab85-f1c8368a375a,4aab51f8-1f4d-4d33-924f-0976bc902b01***

```
@IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  @IsUUID('4', { each: true })
  @Type(() => String)
  @Transform((params) => params.value.split(','))
  readonly ids?: string[];
```

Dont forget to add this to main.ts

```
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transform: true,
    }),
```